# How to have power -1 of an integer?

Tags: c++

I want to have "i" converted to its power -1. But the following code returns zero.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int k;
    cin>>k;
    float reverse;
    for (int i=1; i<=k; i++)
    {
       cout<<i<<"\t";

       reverse = static_cast<float> (1/i);

       cout<< reverse<<endl;
    }
}
```

Should I use pow()?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are dividing an integer by an integer, which always results in an integer (i.e., rounded towards zero). `1 / i` is therefore rounded to 0 for all `i` except 1 (which is 1). *Then* the result is casted to a float (but it will still be a whole numer).

To fix this, let either the numerator or the denominator be a float, because then the result will be a float:

```
reverse = 1.0f / i; // numerator is float and denominator is integer, therefore
                    // the result is a float
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that (1/i) is an integer division, both 1 and i are integers. Integer division in C and C++ has integer results, so it gets rounded down to 0. The static_cast() will only turn that 0 into a floating-point number (0.0), because it's already too late.

What you need to do is to use floating-point division, for which one of the operands needs to be a floating-point number, for example 1.0: writing (1.0/i) will give you a floating point result.